# Lua: "Attempt to index a nill value"

Tags: lua

Hi so I just installed Lua and I have been playing around with it a bit. When I run a program that is supposed to calculate whether an integer is even or odd it throws an error at me.

Program:

```
function is_even(n)
  if bit32.band(n,1) == 0 then
    print('Even')
  else
    print('Odd')
  end
end
```

This is the error that I receive:

```
stdin:2: attempt to index a nil value (global 'bit32')
stack traceback:
        stdin:2: in function 'is_even'
        (...tail calls...)
        [C]: in ?
```

What am i doing wrong here? This program is supposed to work on Lua 5.2+ I currently have Lua 5.3.3 installed.

Comment: How are you invoking this program? It seems to work under the Lua: demo online https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Comment: `if n%2 == 0 then` is more universal solution.

Comment: The above program is exactly what im running in the cmd. And n%2 == 0 works but I wanted to use the new 5.2 bit32 feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bit32` library was deleted from Lua 5.3, because it now supports [bitwise operators](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.2).

Comment: `bit32` is still in Lua 5.3 and is compiled if `LUA_COMPAT_5_2` is defined, which it is in the Makefile from lua.org.